# Não estou conseguindo rodar uma aplicação node.js por conta do jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

Tentei instalar um bootstrap em uma aplicação node.js, ai instalei o jquery e o popper.js, mas agora quando rodo minha aplicação esta dando o seguinte erro.

```
var version = $.fn.jquery.split(' ')[0].split('.');
TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está usando jquery no lado do cliente ou do servidor?

Comment: Já tentou usar, no arquivo `customer.ejs` o *jQuery "normal"* em vez da versão *slim*?

Comment: @MauryDeveloper estou usando do lado do cliente.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr usei o jQuery normal e o slim e nenhum dos dois esta dando certo

Comment: Realmente você descobriu um erro na lib do JQuery, porque para mim não funcionou, quando testei. :v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri como resolver, fiz da seguinte forma, utilizei o jQyery do cdn da google pra pegar o jQuery ai meus script ficaram da seguinte forma

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

e meu link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js">
```